# How can I read the next line from a text file every time I enter the loop?

Tags: c, list, text-files

I have written this program and I want every time I enter the while loop to read the next line from my text file and not the before lines. So far, this code with fscanf inserts in a list all the elements before the one I want. My text files have 4 elements per line and I do not want to read it all as a string also. For example, if the elements from line 1 have entered in the list, the next time in the loop I want to start from line 2 and not to read again the line 1 etc.

```
for(Time=0.0;Time<200;Time=Time+12.0) {
        for(i=5;i<8;i++){
        char to_open[32];
        snprintf(to_open,32, "fptg_%d.txt", i);
        printf("i=%d\n", i);
        if ((fr = fopen(to_open, "r")) == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }else{
            fscanf(fr, "%d %d %d %lf",&rollnumber, &src, &dest, &gentime);
            while(gentime<Time){
                if (insertedpackets[i]<10){ 
                    printf ("-------------TIMESLOT-------------\n");
                    printf("time: %.1f\n",Time);
                    fscanf(fr, "%d %d %d %lf\n",&rollnumber, &src, &dest, &gentime);
                    insert(rollnumber,src,dest,gentime); 
                    insertedpackets[i]++;
                    printf("insertedpackets[%d]:%d\n\n", i, insertedpackets[i]); 
                    printf ("----------list till now-----------\n");
                    display();
                    printf ("----------------------------------\n\n\n\n");
        }
        else if (insertedpackets[i]>=10)
        { 
            break;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: I don't think your real problem has to do with fscanf. I think it's a logic error in your loop. Although, to be honest, I'm guessing about a lot of details which you don't describe. Anyway, if you want to read line by line, use fgets and sscanf. "I don't want to read it all as a string" is an impossible constraint; the data will be read as a string whether you do it explicitly or not

Comment: I understood what you thought. How can I avoid reading the same line without saving each line as a string? Later I want to check each element from each line, so saving it in a list as a whole line will not be helpfull.

Comment: You should read input per line, if lines are important to you. I recommend using `fgets` to read a line into a buffer, and then use `sscanf` to parse that buffer.

Comment: I tried it, but still when I enter the while loop all the lines from the first till the one I want enter again in to the list with the insert function. For example if line 3 has to enter, lines 1-2 enter again, even though they have entered before.

Comment: `fscanf` is *not* reading the same data more than once.  But, if `fscanf` is failing to match the input, then the data in the variables does not change and you may be fooled into believing that it has re-read old data.  You *must* *always* check the value returned by scanf.  You cannot assume that it matches the input. eg `if( fscanf(fr, "%d %d %d %lf\n",...) != 4 ) { fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n"; exit(1);}`

Comment: So, do I need to put the check right after the fscanf command?